# MongoDB 4.2 returns the first n elements from an array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In Mongo 5.2 there is a function called $firstN similarly in mongo 4.2 is there any alternate function or any other way to find the first n elements from a given array?

sample document

```
{
    "id": 1234,
    "products": [
      {
        "productId": 111,
        "path": "H"
      },
      {
        "productId": 112,
        "path": "H"
      },
      {
        "productId": 113,
        "path": "P"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I wanted to return the first n product objects from the product array

With mong 5.2 I can solve this [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6qKoDrN6idL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$slice`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) operator with a similar functionality to take the nth element.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "firstFiveProducts": {
        "$slice": [
          "$products",
          5
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3Kfd7J4YgHO)

Comment: Was about to post this but the page reloaded with your answer. Worth adding, [`$slice` is available for Mongo 4.5](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/), actually [3.2 onwards](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/)